# Python Selenium find element by xpath and click doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, selenium

I've found few questions regarding this topic, but that didn't help me unfortunately.

My code below

```
def gopro(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome() ##PhantomJS() <- that didnt work either
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gpn-header"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/select/option[285]').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.navigate().refresh()
    obj = soup.find('h1', {'class':'price-sales notranslate'})
    print(obj)


print(gopro('https://shop.gopro.com/Marketing/cameras/hero5-black/CHDHX-502-master.html'))
```

I have used Chromebrowser as well, that didnt help either
What I want to do on the website is to get the price of a gopro, but I have to change currency (I need it for 4 currencies (USD,EUR,GBP and NOK) it is located under dropdown form.
upd :
posted screenshots to make it clear, I want a language/currency on the top right dropdown to change from euro to GBP for example
[image: here is what i want]

[image]

Comment: Add some snap of ui. its unclear what you want

Comment: //*[@id="gpn-header"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/select/option[285] , I can see options to select language. Is that what you wanna do ?

Comment: I have updated the post, thanks @NarendraR

Comment: @cruisepandey yeap exactly, language also changes the currency/country, so it works for me

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are trying to change the location value to United Kingdom (GB), English and take the price value of it.

```
def gopro(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome() ##PhantomJS() <- that didnt work either
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gpn-locale-select-current-country-text').click()
    Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gpn-locale-select-selector')).select_by_visible_text('United Kingdom (GB), English')
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.navigate().refresh()
    obj = soup.find('h1', {'class':'price-sales notranslate'})
    print(obj)


print(gopro('https://shop.gopro.com/Marketing/cameras/hero5-black/CHDHX-502-master.html'))
```

Here, I am trying to click on drop down and select the value.

Comment: I think you would need to scroll down too when drop down will be opened.

Comment: @cruisepandey No need, the select class will take care of it.

Comment: got an error 
`    Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gpn-locale-select-selector').select_by_visible_text('United Kingdom (GB), English'))
` 
but ill try to firgure it out

Comment: `AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'select_by_visible_text'`

Comment: sorry, i am missing one closing bracket here. please try with updated code.         Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gpn-locale-select-selector')).select_by_visible_text('United Kingdom (GB), English')

Comment: Unfortunately after multiple attempts, still cant make it :(
tried w/ phantomjs and chrome :(
but w/ chrome it just takes ages to load, that might be the case, but i am not 100% sure gonna try tweaking

Comment: Sorry to bother, but did your script get the result ?
I am super curious, since it just doesn't seem to work in anyway, tho that might be an issue w/ our internet provider or something lol